# How to get Value output of a Geometry node?

Tags: python, scripting, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to get the float value that should be coming out of the float curve node. However, no matter what I try, it always gives me a 0. You can see here what my code says and the incorrect output. The value should be like .9 , but it's not.

```
import bpy

print(bpy.data.node_groups["plant"].nodes["Float Curve"].outputs[0].default_value)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: default_value of an output won't give you what you want.  default_value of the input (in this case CombineXYZ's Z input) that it is connected to should.

Comment: I've tried that and it still doesn't work. It gives me the Z value that I manually entered, not the 0-1 float value that comes from the Float Curve node.

Answer (score 7):

```py
import bpy
C = bpy.context

me = C.object.evaluated_get(C.evaluated_depsgraph_get()).data
field_src = me.attributes[0].data
field = [0.0] * len(field_src)

field_src.foreach_get('value', field)
print(field)
```

it's getting the attribute datas from the evaluated depsgraph.
if there's an error it's probably because of the data type on the `field_src.foreach_get('value', field)`. also if the data you're looking for is wrong, change the index in the `me.attributes[0].data`

the only thing you need to do is to capture attribute it first
[image]

[image]

Comment: How this would change for a vector? I'm trying to get the normal.